# How to customize the domain name of godaddy in heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns, web-deployment

I have successfully added my domain name of go daddy into my Heroku app .. but DNS target is getting something else . I have changed target in go daddy but still It is not showing the correct one . please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Please read [the Heroku doc on custom domain names](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).
Make sure you've done all of the steps below, and remember there can be a delay before DNS changes are noticeable.

1. Confirm that you own the custom domain name.
   You can buy a custom domain name with a domain registration service.
2. Add the custom domain to your app with the heroku domains:add
   command.
3. Look up the Heroku-supplied DNS target for the custom domain using
   the heroku domains command.
4. Configure your app’s DNS provider to point to the Heroku-supplied
   DNS target.
5. Confirm that your app is accessible via the custom domain.
   There might be a delay while DNS changes propagate.